# External Interrupt 0 doesn't work

Tags: c, initialization, interrupt, avr, atmega

Can anybody figure out why my external interrupt 0 doesn't work? I am using an AVR STK 500 board with an ATmega164P on it. Is it because the pin D2 has got two functions?

```
#include <asf.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>

ISR(INT0_vect)
{
    PORTB = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTB << 1;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    board_init();

    sei();

    PORTD = 0xFF;
    DDRD = 0x00;
    PORTB = 0x00;
    DDRB = 0xFF;

    while(1)
    {
        PORTB = PIND;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does board_init() do? Do you setup/enable the external interrupt?

Comment: Don't `delay` inside an ISR.

Comment: Just to emphasis JimmyB's statement, do not put delay inside an ISR.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you don't enable the external interrupt.

Look at the data sheet section 10.2.

> 10.2.2 EIMSK – External Interrupt Mask Register
>
> > When an INT2:0 bit is written to one and the I-bit in the Status Register (SREG) is set (one), the corresponding external pin interrupt is enabled. The Interrupt Sense Control bits in the External Interrupt Control Register,
> >     EICRA, defines whether the external interrupt is activated on rising or falling edge or level sensed.

So you have to set

```
EIMSK |= (1 << INT0);
```

to enable INT0 and potentially `EICRA` to define what signal edge you want to react at.

Comment: This `EIMSK |= (1<<INT0)`, would be a more transparent way to set that bit.

Comment: @BenceKaulics: Absolutely, forgive me demonstrating bad coding practice :)

Comment: It was just an improvement request to make a good answer better. :)